# How can a data matrix be made where the column data matches the row number and is replaced by 1, the rest by 0 in RStudio?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I would appreciate if you can help me to make an array of activities (1:49) for column and row, where the data is exported from a dataframe (expressing the precedence of the activity by number), the number found in the column represents the precedence number per row, that is, if column 9 has precedence 8, the relationship must be expressed by replacing row 8 of column 9 with 1 and the rest of the data in the rows by 0, attached as desired by the Outcome.
and that if it has as data 0 it means that it has no precedents skipping that column.
n = length of Predj

```
    > DB$Predj
    [1] 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11 12 13  0 14 16 17 18  0  0 18 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29  0 29 32 33 34
    [36] 0 34 37 38 39  0  0  0 43 44 45 46 47
    matrixPredj <- matrix(c(DB$Predj), nrow=length(n), ncol=length(n), byrow=TRUE)
           colnames(matrixPredj)<- c (1:length(n))
           rownames(matrixPredj)<- c (1:length(n))

for (i in 1:ncol(matrixPredj)){
           Mmatrix <- as.matrix(dtmatrix);dtmatrix <- matrixPredj[,i]
           valuevector <- Mmatrix[1,1]
           Mmatrix[valuevector,]=1
```

I lack the restriction that if it is 0 continue with another column, in addition to eliminating the values other than 1, I want to pass it to a list and then with all the results put together a new dataframe, I would think that I can do it like this, who knows more would appreciate it .

the matrix by column will repeat the value in all its rows in order to find the row with the same value as shown below

I want it to look like this (example)

.`

```
 ...1   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `7`   `8`   `9`
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
2     2     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
3     3     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
4     4     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
5     5     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
6     6     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
7     7     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
8     8     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
9     9     0     0     1     0     1     3     4     1     7
```

OUTCOME

```
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    1    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: What is `n`? ...

Comment: n is the DB $ Predj count

Comment: 'count' of what?

Comment: I had thought of taking it as a list and then putting together a new dataframe with the data, an example by column I have done so
for (i in 1: ncol (matrixPredj)) {
            Mmatrix <- as.matrix (dtmatrix); dtmatrix <- matrixPredj [, i]
            valuevector <- Mmatrix [1,1]
            Mmatrix [valuevector,] = 1
although I still don't know how to add the restriction that if the value is 0 continue; In the last line of code I could select the row and replace it with 1, what comes next is that the values other than 1 become 0

Comment: The problem I want to represent are activities that are designated by number, so I import the excel data and n is the count of the total value of DB $ Predj (in this case 49), with the objective that regardless of how much data is put into place, the matrix according to need

Comment: The matrix appears to be created with a vector of length `n`, but then you specify that you have `n` rows and `n` columns. Don't you see the difficulty in that effort?

Comment: I'm recently learning the language to solve a problem, create the matrix like that and then name its rows and columns 1:49 so that it doesn't appear by default [, n], from what I understand it's fine like this, it doesn't have effort

Comment: This is not an issue with the R language. An n x n matrix has n^2  values but you are only providing n values. In your explanation you should try to break up that extremely long sentence into several discrete sentences.